# Default Parameters in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I would like to make my Dialogflow country-specific such that when my chatbot starts, I like to pass it some parameters eg country and then to insert the country parameter into the intent which is passed onto my backend. Is that possible? I can't seem to find any information regarding that in the docs or maybe, I might have missed out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your integration is via the Dialogflow APIs or using the Dialogflow Client Library, then you can pass the country in the session ID, and then extract the country from the session ID in fulfillment using agent.session.

Comment: Thanks @ErraticEggplant for the directions. I will check it out! I need to use the country info to trigger country-specific intent